# What objects can be found in the universe when all the stars are gone?

Tags: universe

Far in the future, in a termic death of the universe scenario, what objects are still around to see?

Will planets still be around, gas clouds, black holes, star remnants? Any other new or old types of objects?

Comment: Wikipedia has a quite readable page on [the Future of The Expanding Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe).

Comment: Just noticed them talking about that when I turned on he TV: *How the Universe Works* [S3E2](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+the+universe+works+season+3+episode+2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is hard to answer exactly because your terms are not precice.  Do you mean stars have all stopped undergoing fusion, or all the [white dwarfs have finally stopped glowing from residual heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_dwarf) (a *million trillion* years later)?

You need to find a [detailed timeline of the future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe) in a non-fiction site.

In general, there will be dust, gas that never made it into a star, planets, smaller lumps of matter, etc. still carrying on, on this time scale.  They simply get much farther apart.  The “local group” of galaxies, probably one big ellipitcal galaxy by then (coalesce in a mere trillion years), will stay together thus far, with all the now-black dwarfs, neutron stars, black holes, “rogue planets”, cooled brown dwarves, oort clouds, etc. still gravitationally bound together.

## New types

Well, white dwarves will have cooled to make black dwarves. None have done so yet.  Tiny red dwarves will burn out eventually (like ten trillion years), leaving a new kind of remnant; none have done so yet.  Likewise, you will find *frozen* rather than hot Jupiter-sized through brown dwarf balls of hydrogen and helium.

Before all the stars burn out, you will have a gradual shift to stars with more *stuff* besides hydrogen and helium.  Perhaps this will produce things that are different enough in how they burn to warrant a [new category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_population).

Comment: Plus, the black holes will all eventually evaporate.

Comment: @Spencer that will happen *much* later. They will still be around when the stars are gone.  Supermassive BH in particular will not start evaporating at all until the CMB temperature [drops below the BH’s temperature](https://phys.org/news/2016-09-cold-black-holes.html).  You’d have to check on [Physics.se] or [astronomy.se] for low long it will be before even the stellar-mass BH will start to evaporate, dropping the CMB between 7 and 8 orders of magnitude.

Comment: Nevertheless it will happen, and OP wasn't terribly specific. A quick googling turned up an evaporation time of 10^67 years for a one solar mass black hole.

Comment: Is seems like the author's question is asking what [Degenerate Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe#Degenerate_Era) would look like.